# Discord.js "Expected a string primitive" when showing modal

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error: `ValidationError: Expected a string primitive` when running a simple command that should just show a simple modal in Discord.js v14:

```
import {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
  TextInputStyle,
} from 'discord.js'
import { SlashCommand } from '../types/discord'
import {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  ModalBuilder,
  TextInputBuilder,
} from '@discordjs/builders'

const TestCommand: SlashCommand = {
  command: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('modaltest')
    .setDescription('Shows a test modal')
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages),

  execute: (interaction) => {
    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
      .setTitle('Test modal')
      .setCustomId('test_modal')

    const input = new TextInputBuilder()
      .setCustomId('test_input')
      .setPlaceholder('Test input')
      .setRequired(true)
      .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)

    modal.addComponents(
      new ActionRowBuilder<TextInputBuilder>().addComponents(input),
    )

    interaction.showModal(modal)

    return interaction.reply({ content: 'Modal shown' })
  },
  cooldown: 10,
}

export default TestCommand
```

This is the full error:

```
/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/src/validators/StringValidator.ts:73
                return this.ip(6);
                  ^
ValidationError: Expected a string primitive
    at StringValidator.handle (/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/src/validators/StringValidator.ts:73:19)
    at StringValidator.parse (/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/src/validators/BaseValidator.ts:103:2)
    at validateRequiredParameters (/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/src/components/textInput/Assertions.ts:26:17)
    at TextInputBuilder.toJSON (/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/src/components/textInput/TextInput.ts:135:3)
    at /home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/src/components/ActionRow.ts:132:61
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ActionRowBuilder.toJSON (/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/src/components/ActionRow.ts:132:32)
    at /home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/src/interactions/modals/Modal.ts:98:61
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ModalBuilder.toJSON (/home/nobypass/dev/fds-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/src/interactions/modals/Modal.ts:98:32) {
  validator: 's.string',
  given: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TextInputBuilder is missing a `label` attribute.

```js
const input = new TextInputBuilder()
      .setCustomId('test_input')
      .setPlaceholder('Test input')
      .setRequired(true)
      .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setLabel('Enter Input'); // add this
```